# Making OWL data and object properties sub-properties of the same property

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, triplestore, triples

Suppose I have the classes:

```
> Element
> ElementProperty
```

With the subclasses of `elementProperty` being:

```
> AtomicNumber
> AtomicMass
```

Also consider the following object properties and their domains and ranges:

```
> hasElementProperty
  Domain:Element
  Range:ElementProperty
```

Where `hasElementProperty` has the following sub-properties:

```
> hasAtomicNumber
  Domain:Element
  Range:AtomicNumber
> hasAtomicMass
  Domain:Element
  Range:AtomicMass
```

So this way when I say `:Lithium :hasAtomicNumber :3` the triple `:Lithium :hasElementProperty :3` will be inferred, where `:3` is an instance of the `AtomicNumber` class.

Okay so now consider the case where I have the data property `hasElementName` and I also want it so that when I have the triple `:Lithium :hasElementName "Lithium"` the triple `:Lithium :hasElementProperty "Lithium"` is inferred. This isn't possible with the way I have it set up now as `hasElementName` is a data property and thus cannot be a sub-property of the object property `hasElementProperty`.
I have tried using Literal Reification (see [Literal Reification](http://www.essepuntato.it/lode/owlapi/http://www.essepuntato.it/2010/06/literalreification)) with success, but I feel like there may be a better way to do this as literal reification's purpose is so one can use literals as objects, and that's not what I need to do. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want/need to have this generic "hasElementProperty" property to being with?

Comment: This set up was just for the purposes of describing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in OWL 2 DL, only in OWL 2 FULL - which means reasoners and tools might complain about your ontology, or you might get unexpected results.

If collecting all values under the same property is necessary to your application, I would keep using literal reification - seems to be the simplest way to achieve the desired result.